# Validate user input text to see if it's a syntactically correct javascript function

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, validation, dsl

I am implementing a service which uses Domain Specific Language (DSL) written in the form of javascript functions. I am trying to accept the rules via UI. The rules will be a string that the user inputs in a textarea in the UI. Is there a way to validate if the user input text is a valid javascript function in the frontend (using javascript/jquery some such mechanism)

I am currently doing it the backend below and catching exception to see if it fails:

```
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
engine.eval(new FileReader("script.js"));
```

Sample rule:

```
var rules = function(inputMap) {
  // boilerplate
  var Attribution = Java.type('com.sunapana.type.Attribution');
  var attr = new Attribution("Unknown", "Unknown", "Unknown");

  // logic
  if (inputMap.shareId != null && inputMap.shareId.length > 0) {
    attr = new Attribution("Sharing", inputMap.source, inputMap.shareId);
  } else (inputMap.refTag != null && inputMap.refTag.length > 0) {
    attr = new Attribution("Marketing", inputMap.source, inputMap.refTag);
  }
  return attr;
};
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: javascript also has `eval()` and `try...catch`...not sure if that would work for you

Comment: Try to avoid `eval`, it's evil. Why don't you just run it through a JavaScript parser like [esprima](http://esprima.org/)? If it can build an AST, it's valid JavaScript.